# Make POST request with file and xml content

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I am trying to make a POST request to an api server.

I have a request body which is an xml parameter:

```
<create-user>
    <user-name>username1</user-name>
    <password>password1</password>
</create-user>
```

Next to this parameter, i also need so send a file.

I've tried with fiddler the following thing, but the data is not received by the server (the file exists, but the `<create-user>` parameter not.

Is possible to send a combination of xml parameters with uploaded files?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Just add boundary mark (and "Content-Type: application/xml") before XML body. Like the following:

```
------yxz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="formInputXML"
Content-Type: application/xml

<create-user>...</create-user
------xyz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="formInputFile"; filename="UserData.xml"
Content-Type: text/xml

<UserData.xml content>
------xyz--
```